# Массивы нулевой длины

Tags: массивы, c, linux

Сегодня случайно натолкнулся на статью [Применение специальных возможностей GCC в ядре Linux](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-gcc-hacks/), в которой есть следущие строки:

> Массивы нулевой длины
>
> Согласно стандарту С, для массива необходимо определить как минимум один элемент. Как правило, это требование усложняет проектирование кода. Однако GCC поддерживает концепцию массивов нулевой длины, которые могут быть особенно полезны при определении структур данных. Эта концепция похожа на гибкие элементы массива в ISO C99, но использует другой синтаксис.
>
> В следующем примере в конце структуры объявляется массив нулевой длины (из ./linux/drivers/ieee1394/raw1394-private.h). Это позволяет экземпляру этой структуры ссылатся на память, следующую непосредственно за ней. Это может быть полезно, когда вам необходимо иметь переменное количество элементов в массиве.
>
> ```
> struct iso_block_store {
>     atomic_t refcount;
>     size_t data_size;
>     quadlet_t data[0];
> };
> ```

Меня удивило предложение *"Это может быть полезно, когда вам необходимо иметь переменное количество элементов в массиве"*, и именно в связи с ним возникло два вопроса:

1. **Почему `data[0]`, когда можно воспользоваться классическим `data *` ?**
2. **Как для `data[0]` выделяется память под это самое "переменное количество элементов в массиве", то есть как ведётся с ним работа?**

Спасибо.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Потому что массив при таком определении будет частью структуры, то есть, расположен с ней в общем куске памяти. В случае с `quadlet_t *data`, для данных необходимо будет выделить новый кусок, отдельный от `struct iso_block_store`.
2. Например, так:

   ```
   struct iso_block_store *store =
           malloc(sizeof(struct iso_block_store) +
                     sizeof(quadlet_t) * number_of_data_items);
   ```

Обращаться к элементу просто: `store->data[i]`.

---

Технически говоря, доступ к массиву за пределами объявленного размера есть undefined behaviour ([обсуждение на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3711233/276994)). Однако, многие компиляторы (включая gcc и MSVC) ведут ожидаемым образом.

---

Необходимое позднее дополнение. Если задекларировать последнее поле в таком виде:

```
quadlet_t data[];
```

— то в более-менее современных версиях языка C (по крайней мере C99) это будет работать без UB, если только вы, конечно, не «вылезете» за выделенную память. В стандарте C99 про это говорится в §6.7.2.1/15, а также можно почитать [здесь](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct) (ищите «flexible array member»). Спасибо @wololo за подсказку!

Comment: @VladD, очень простой и естественный ответ. настолько простой, что я не сразу понял, почему я не вышел на него самостоятельно - я думал, что память нужно будет выделять конкретно под этот массив, а вы выделяете память сразу под всю структуру с запасом. А дальше всё очевидно - массив - это указатель на первый элемент, поэтому адресация происходит безотносительно того, сколько в нём объявлено элементов. Спасибо :)

Comment: Меня в своё время поразила эта конструкция, так что я её хорошо запомнил.

---
Пожалуйста!

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich: обратите внимание, это одно из тех мест, в которых массив и указатель — не одно и то же.

Comment: > @Stanislaw Pankevich: обратите внимание, это одно из тех мест, в которых массив и указатель — не одно и то же.

Можете, пожалуйста, чуть подробнее?

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich: ну, в С во многих контекстах массив и указатель — одно и то же. Например, в аргументах функции:

    void main(int argc, char* argv[]);

и

    void main(int argc, char** argv);

— совершенно одно и то же. Для как указателя, так и массива `p` значение выражения `p[i]` — одно и то же. Ну и ещё во многих местах. Попробую найти примеры на SO. А ещё, в тред призывается @avp :-)

---
О, вот же каноническая ссылка: <http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/> (особенно <http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html>).

Ещё одна: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/01/11/pointers-to-arrays-in-c

Comment: Мне нужно время, чтобы прочитать. Спасибо.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, такая конструкция может быть полезной при реализации хэш-таблицы `key:value` для Objects в **spj**.

А так, @VladD уже все здесь расписал и я не знаю, что добавить.

Разве только добавить предостережение, что при  `realloc` структуры с целью изменения количества элементов массива адрес самой структуры тоже изменится, следовательно надо будет корректировать указатели на нее из других структур.

Comment: @avp: мне был бы интересен ваш комментарий по поводу отличия массивов и указателей. Хотя, это тема для большого вопроса.

Comment: > @avp: мне был бы интересен ваш комментарий по поводу отличия массивов и указателей. Хотя, это тема для большого вопроса.

@VladD, а попробуйте открыть тогда новый вопрос? Я бы сам открыл, просто не до конца понимаю, какой сделать формулировку. Должно быть интересно.

Comment: По существу массив и указатель на первый его элемент различаются в контексте, где отводится память под массив. А переданные как параметр эквивалентны.

Например, так писать нельзя

     int a[10], *pa = a, // можно
         **ppa = &a;     // нельзя

а так можно

     foo (int a[]) {
        int *ppa = &a;

только это особого смысла не имеет, т.к. мы получим адрес ячейки в стеке, в которой лежит адрес первого элемента массива (или копия указателя на него), изменения этой ячейки все равно пропадут после возврата.

Comment: Вероятно спустя столько лет это уже не важно... Но если заменить объявление в конце структуры `quadlet_t data[0];` на `quadlet_t data[];`, то никакого UB не будет, и пользоваться таким массивом можно в точности так, как описано в ответе. См.: [flexible array member](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct).

Comment: @wololo: Почему же неважно? Спасибо, дополню ответ. Ars longa, vita brevis.