# Как использовать new со структурой переменного размера?

Tags: c++, c

В Си иногда использовался такой подход: [tio.run](https://tio.run/##Vc1NDoIwEAXgfU/xgjFpQY3KsspFDAtsizQp/yUhGs@OraDR3cw3fa@iabY3IaZppSthBqlw6q00@rorEvJnuvZEetsNwqIvbYEHAXTlFn1XfJllZrPLPuXkyQnxUGa6ooz4t@9QOOIM6seQlZkxtaA@X@czMkSIEeJjroIxXz5uE28uHC/r8pWTw68cvBx/5ZjOKUd53b070Z73HO1paeWIopa5O9B07pzTYC0RbL4VbcrmfKcUHd38nKYX)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct smth {
  int size;
  int data[0];
};

int main()
{
  smth *x = (smth*)malloc(sizeof (smth) + 3 * sizeof (int));
  x->size = 3;
  x->data[0] = 1;
  x->data[1] = 2;
  x->data[2] = 3;

  for (int q=0; q<x->size; ++q)
    printf("%d ", x->data[q]);

  free(x);
}
```

Есть ли у него аналог в Си++? Как выделить память нужного размера через new?

Comment: Как понять структура  переменного размера?  Имеется ввиду ее представление?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, имеется в виду то, что показано в коде. Под структуру выделяется больше памяти, чем её sizeof и хвостовая часть этой памяти используется как массив данных соответствующего размера.

Comment: все равно не соглашусь. Не под структуру выделяется больше памяти, а  выделяется больше памяти, на которую указывает указатель типа. Это то же самое, что  делать  reinterpret_cast<char*>(new std::pair<int, int>({ 2, 3 })); Это не значит, что  размер char изменился

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, ладно, а как тогда это правильно называется? И что по теме? А то полученный ответ меня смущает, и под ним есть комментарий, чем именно.

Comment: В С++ нет структур переменного размера и массивов с 0 элементами. Память можно выделить как обычно, а разместить объекты посредством placement new

Comment: `int data[0];` нужно заменить на `int data[];`, иначе UB. См.: [Массивы нулевой длины](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/297649).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начнем с того, что ваш код - невалидный C/C++. Его можно сделать валидным C, заменив `[0]` на `[]` и исправив `smth` на `struct smth`.

Такой массив без размера в конце структуры называется [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member), их нет в C++.

---

Но можно самостоятельно соорудить альтернативу.

Для этого убираете массив из класса: `struct smth {int size;};`, и дальше вычисляете адрес "массива" относительно `this`, что-то типа `reinterpret_cast<char *>(this) + sizeof(*this)`. Потом [выровнять](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align) указатель (в вашем случае нет необходимости), и для надежности можно "отмыть" результат через [`std::launder`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder).

У меня нет полной уверенности, что такие манипуляции с адресами легальны (даже с `std::launder`), но я не верю, что такой популярный прием сломается на практике, поэтому неважно.

**Проблема:** хочется мочь писать `delete x;`, вместо того чтобы руками делать `x->~MyClass(); operator delete(x);` (где `operator delete()` - это плюсовая замена `free(&x)`).

Многоуважаемый @ueber откопал ссылку на [`P0722R1`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0722r1.html) (который попал в C++20, см. конкретные изменения в стаднарте в [`P0722R3`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0722r3.html)), который объясняет, что просто так писать `delete x;` для таких классов нельзя - ведь теперь в `operator delete()` вторым параметром автоматически передается размер куска памяти, т.е. `sizeof(T)`. (Пишут, что это дает возможность делать более эффективные аллокаторы.) Т.к. в вашем случае `sizeof(T)` и размер блока памяти не совпадают, вы получаете UB.

`P0722R1` объясняет решение: внутрь класса нужно добавить

```
void operator delete(void *ptr) {::operator delete(ptr);}
```

Это блокирует передачу размера класса в `operator delete`, и убирает UB. Но `P0722R1` также объясняет, что "безразмерная" версия `operator delete` может работать медленнее, чем версия с размером.

Можно было бы самостоятельно передать размер блока памяти в `operator delete`, вычислив его из поля `size` вашего класса, вот так: `void operator delete(void *ptr) {::operator delete(ptr, размер);}`. Но его невозможно нормально сделать, потому что деструктор вашего класса уже отработал, и попытка прочитать `size` вызовет неопределенное поведение, даже если вы не меняли его значение в деструкторе.

Поэтому в C++20 (этим `P0722R3`) был добавлен т.н. *destroying `operator delete`* ("разрушающий" вариант delete).

Он используется следующим образом:

```
struct A
{
    int size = 0;

    void operator delete(A *a, std::destroying_delete_t)
    {
        std::size_t mem_size = sizeof(A) + a->size * sizeof(int);
        a->~A();
        ::operator delete((void*)a, mem_size);
    };
};
```

Добавляя параметр `std::destroying_delete_t` вы отказываетесь от автоматического вызова деструктора, и должны сделать это сами (поэтому "разрушающий"). Это позволяет вам прочитать поля класса до вызова деструктора, и вычислить из них размер освобождаемой памяти. Также тип первого параметра меняется с `void *` на `MyClass *`. (Что интересно, в Clang-е `delete` с размером во втором параметре компилируется только с доп. флагом - `-fsized-deallocation`.)

---

Остается только написать красивую функцию для выделения нужного объема памяти и создания в ней объекта. Что-то в духе:

```
void *ptr = ::operator new(sizeof(A) + size * sizeof(int));
return new(ptr) A(size);
```

В той же самой `P0722R1` есть интересная идея: делать это вычисление в кастомном `operator new` внутри класса:

```
struct A
{
    int size = 0;

    A(int size) : size(size) {}

    void *operator new(std::size_t n, int x)
    {
        return ::operator new(n + x * sizeof(int));
    }

    // ... operator delete ...
};
```

И вызывается эта бандура так: `new(n) A(n);` (где первый `n` передается в `new`, а второй в конструктор). В чем профит такого подхода - непонятно. Все равно надо заворачивать в функцию, чтобы два раза не писать размер, и чтобы возвращать сразу умный указатель.

---

Если хотите делать такой класс шаблоном, для произвольных типов, еще нужно особым образом обрабатывать типы с большим выравниванием (больше `__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__`). Есть специальные перегрузки `operator new`/`operator delete`, принимающие выравнивание - про них надо гуглить отдельно.

Comment: Если g++ поддерживает `int data[];` то ведь можно его использовать? А ещё, похоже, что в `operator delete` надо ещё `sizeof (A)` прибавить к размеру?

Comment: @Qwertiy Ой, действительно, добавил. Можно, кто ж вам запретит... Но тогда фен-шуй требует проверить это на всех основных компиляторах, и обложить `pragma`ми, чтобы компилировалось даже с `-pedantic-errors`.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понимаю, то речь идет о том, как поместить экземпляр  структуры в память переменного размера оператором new. Иначе говоря, это  `new  с размещением`. Примерно сделаю то, что показано в вопросе по возможности примитивно, чтобы было понятней:

```
 struct smth {
    char i{ 'a' };   
};

int main()
{    
    char* s1 = new char[5]; 
    // разместить  smth в s1
    smth* ps = new(s1)(smth);
    //инициализация массива через smth
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
         (ps + i)->i = 'a' + i; //abcde
    //ставим символ конца, чтобы использовать
    s1[4] = '\0';
    //и выводим результат
    std::cout << '\n' << s1; //abcd
    delete[]s1;
    //теперь берем другой участок памяти
    s1 = new char[16];
    //разместить  smth в s1
    smth* ps1 = new(s1)(smth);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 15; ++i)
        (ps1 + i)->i = 'z' - i; //abcde
    s1[14] = '\0';
    std::cout << '\n' << s1;
    //zyxwvutsrqponm
    
    delete[]s1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Указатель `ps` указывает на один объект типа `smth`, который для целей арифметики указателей можно рассматривать как массив из одного элемента. Следовательно в цикле `for` выход за пределы массива, что есть UB. Там же в цикле обращаемся к несуществующим экземплярам класса `smth`, что также UB.

Comment: @wololo, вы правы(На счет не существующего) , если только это не для демонстрации, В данном случаи smth сосотоит из одного символа, которого можно инициализировать из любой памяти.  И в цикле for нет выхода за пределы массива, так как адрес объекта совпадает с  адресом первого элемента массива, и размеры совпадают.

Comment: `smth сосотоит из одного символа, которого можно инициализировать из любой памяти` Из тривиальности объекта не следует, что его можно инициализировать из любой памяти. Иначе можно столкнуться с ошибкой [наподобие такой](https://rextester.com/WBRFE59038). `И в цикле for нет выхода за пределы массива` Есть. [Более простой пример](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de9561444a51c94b). Обратите внимание на текст сообщения об ошибке.

Comment: @wololo, еще раз утверждаю _ адрес любого POD объекта можно кастить на char*  и записать все что там есть. Не безопасно? Безусловно. Но возможно. То что вы называете более простым примером, является совершенно другим примером. Там массив двумерный,. Вы выходите за пределы строки.

Comment: В вашем коде нет каста к `char*` всё совсем наоборот, вы кусок массива типа `char` переинтерпретируете     как объект типа `smth`, коим он не является. Это UB, и внутреннее устройство типа `smth` роли не играет. В C++ нет двумерных массивов. В моём примере одномерный массив, элементами которого являются одномерные массивы. Я вышел за пределы массива из 10 элементов типа `int`. Вы вышли за пределы массива из одного элемента типа `smth`. Так ли велика разница...

Comment: Да, разница велика. Но я не говорил, что это не UB, я говорил, что это не код, а демонстрация оператора  new с размещением.

Comment: `&arr[0][0]` имеет тип `const int*`, а `arr[0]` имеет тип `const int[10]`, и это не то же самое. Если игнорировать UB, то указатель `&arr[0][0] + 11` указывает на элемент с индексом `1` строки с индексом `1`. [Тест](https://rextester.com/XHUGU82078).

Comment: @wololo, спасибо за отзывы и замечания. Приятно было поспорить, но уже разворачиваемся... На тему структуры, хранящий один символ было много споров, но почти все компиляторы его воспринимают как просто символ(в любых тестах)

Answer (score 1):

Подобному юзкейсу посвящено одно из изменений в 20 стандарт - https://wg21.link/p0722. В нём приводится пример класса переменного размера:

```
class inlined_fixed_string {
  public:
   inlined_fixed_string() = delete;
   const size_t size() const { return size_; }

   const char *data() const {
     return static_cast<const char *>(this + 1);
   }

   // operator[], etc, with obvious implementations

   inlined_fixed_string *Make(const std::string &data) {
     size_t full_size = sizeof(inlined_fixed_string) + data.size();
     return new(::operator new(full_size))
                  inlined_fixed_string(data.size(), data.c_str());
   }

  private:
   inlined_fixed_string(size_t size, const char *data) : size_(size) {
     memcpy(data(), data, size);
   }
   size_t size_;
};
```

Comment: А если тип не char? К `char*` можно привести любой указатель, а к другим указателям - нет. И кто даёт гарантию, что `this+1` имеет правильное выравнивание для целевого типа?

Comment: Это класс,  работающий с памятью переменного размера, а не класс переменного размера, которого и не может быть.  Можно сказать класс с примитивным аллокатором.. С таким успехом можно просто хранить в классе std::string::iterator

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, да ну? Вот я легко получил int с нечётным адресом: [tio.run](https://tio.run/##dVJBboMwELz7FSv1UEgTJb0amh/0BVWFHLNJrIJB9pKgRnk7XdtpWqkUJHvNDOuZsXXfrw5aT9ODsboZaoTSdJ4cqnYrhG6U92BsYyzW1d6MPDJo7AEuAqAfdo3RkqtZTpbDC9TYIGEROLqznsCbT6zSxIT07QIOaXA2gQVcRepJsKgVKeaF7fi50Rwyhq7nZaWVpzJStxkdjYcneM7jfqnLeg1dj05R597el4Ckl3A2dIRudzLdwPbavsEWLSkyrCb@5MNCzztfvKoPzAbrzYEx0Eflou67yJvD/dA0Vag5hTB1@2yuX86CI2txYwHTKDm4G7Z4zqT89hGX9/Z5Pp9@xH6C6J05KcL/T2vOkUxmsl/@Uqp/yVUhroUQ4SRaZWyWi0CfT3DkSOYQKWO2z5uo21Mtpe4GgrKEMQyP/IZ6tU3XIrDSBYOxCLpucW1YyzR9AQ).

Comment: Этот пропосал был внесён в стандарт языка? В каких пунктах стандарта описываются _variable sized classes_ (или как правильно называется конструкция в вашем ответе)?

Comment: Кстати, ещё момент. А как освобождается выделенная таким образом память? Чую, тут тоже подвох.

Comment: Упоминание destroying delete очень к месту, но почему вы привели в пример именно этот класс - непонятно. Он же тут не используется. Это пример неправильно написанного класса, где он нужен.

Answer (score 1):

В плюсах такого нет. Приходится использовать ручное выделение памяти и вызовы конструктов и деструкторов. Переделываем пример на классы, для демонстрации работы.

```
# include <iostream>

class A {
public:
  int i{};
  A(){std::cout<<"A() "<<std::flush;}
  ~A(){std::cout<<"~A() "<<std::flush;}
};

class C {
public  :
  size_t  size  { 0 } ;
  inline  A * Data  ( ) { return  ( A * ) ( this + 1 ) ; }
  C ( size_t ) ;
  ~ C ( ) ;
} ;

C :: C ( size_t const s ) : size { s } {
  std::cout<<"C() "<<std::flush;
  new ( Data  ( ) ) A [ s ] ;
}

C :: ~C ( ) {
  A * a = Data  ( ) ;
  for ( size_t  i = 0 ; i < size ; ++ i , ++ a )
    a -> ~ A ( ) ;
  std::cout<<"~C() "<<std::endl;
}

int main  ( ) {
  int const s = 3 ;
  C * const cp  = ( C * ) :: operator new
    ( sizeof ( C ) + sizeof ( A [ s ] ) ) ;
  new ( cp  ) C ( s ) ;
  cp -> ~ C ( ) ;
  :: operator delete ( cp ) ;
}
```

проверяем

```
$ ./vararray 
C() A() A() A() ~A() ~A() ~A() ~C()
```

То есть выделяем голую память под класс C плюс массив.

Конструктор вызываем вручную.

В конструкторе класса C делаем ручные вызовы конструкторов в дополнительном массиве.

Деструктор класса вызываем вручную.

При вызове деструктора C он будет сам вызывать вручную деструкторы вектора и дальше сам очищается.

Отдаём выделенную голую память.