# Почему массив выводит что-то, если он пустой?

Tags: c++, массивы

Начал изучать массивы и столкнулся с вопросом, почему данный массив что-либо выводит, если он будто бы пустой.

```
int val[] = {};
cout << val[0]; // -136178632
cout << val[1]; // 1
```

Comment: Весна на улице... Огороды. Дачник приходит и свои там 6 соток делит на 6 участков по сотке. Это — массив "овощи" из 6 элементов. Тут картошка, там - помидорки... Это он массив инициализирует :) Но ведь до того, как он что-то посадил - там ведь тоже что-то росло? Да хоть бурьян? Вот так и у вас — в неинициализированном массиве какие-то числа, оставшиеся в памяти от последнего использования, грубо говоря... Кстати, а как вы себе представляете "пустое число"? Что это? :)

Comment: Похоже, вам еще надо бы почитать и об указателях. На самом деле, массив это не что иное, как адрес в памяти. В ней резервируется место нужное для хранения заданного при определении массива количества его элементов. Только вот, при обращении к элементам массива никто его границ не проверяет... (в памяти, соответствующей не существующим элементам массива может быть что угодно)

Comment: Мой g++ в принципе отказывается это компилировать

Comment: 1) В C++ массивы нулевого размера запрещены (кроме динамических). По-хорошему программа не должна компилироваться. См. пример в [параграфе Process на cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). 2) Некоторые компиляторы [имеют расширение языка](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html), которое позволяет объявлять массивы нулевого размера. Их используют для создания «гибких массивов» (_flexible array member_). [См. вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/297649). 3) Здесь никаких гибких массивов нет, а просто выход за пределы массива.

Comment: ...Поведение программы не определено. Она может делать что угодно. Например, аварийно завершиться или вывести «мусорные» значения со стека. 4) Массив указателем **не** является — это самостоятельная сущность. В некоторых контекстах массив может быть _неявно преобразован_ в указатель на свой первый элемент, но так происходит не всегда. Например, посмотрите на [вывод](https://godbolt.org/z/vMT17v55n) такой программы: `const char  arr[] = "12"; const char* ptr   = "12"; cout << sizeof(arr) << " " << sizeof(ptr) << endl; cout << std::is_same<decltype(arr), decltype(ptr)>::value << endl;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ну ты вышел за границы массива и тебе просто мусор из памяти скидывает

val[] оно же int* val; - указатель на первый элемент массива(нулевой)
int == 4 байта, значит ты сдвинулся допустим с ячейка 0x0016 на 0x0020, оттуда ты достал единицу. можешь перезапустить ide и цифры скорее всего будут другими, а могут повториться. зависит от того какой участок памяти сейчас доступен.